# Image won't resize using media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to resize an image on a `html` page when it is displayed on a browser.

The `HTML` used us as follows;

```
<body class="layout-4">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header id="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="site-logo">
                            <img class="logoimage" src="assets/images/emailsig.png" alt="Logo Image" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10 align-right">
                        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <nav id="main-menu" class="collapse" role="navigation">
                            <ul class="nav-menu clearfix">
                                <li><a href="#wrapper">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#about">Specialisms</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#feature1">Contextual</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#feature2">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#how-it-works">Media</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
                                <li class="phone-call"><a href="callto:+44 12345678">Phone  </a>/<a href="mailto:email">   Email</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav><!-- /#main-menu -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.container -->
            <div class="back-to-top">
                <!-- Back to top button -->
                <a href="#wrapper"><img src="assets/images/arrow-top.png" alt="Back to Top" title="Back to Top" /></a>
            </div>
        </header><!-- /#header -->
```

I am using a number of `media queries` for different resolutions (will paste one example below)

```
@media screen and max-width1200px {
    div.site-logo {
        max-width:70%;
    }

    img.logoimage {
        max-width:1%;
    }
}
```

Now as my understanding goes, this should set the total space allowed for the `div` that the image is in to `70%` of the total width of the page, and then my image should be allowed just a `max-width` of `1%` (this is so small because I just wanted to test that it was working). The image however still extends well off of the edge of the page on my iPhone.

How else can an image be scaled to fit a mobile screen correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be :

```
    @media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
        div.site-logo {
            max-width:70%;
        }

        img.logoimage {
            max-width:1%;
        }
    }
```

Comment: so i am missing parenthesis? and a colon

Comment: and the `:` before 1200px

Comment: it still extends over the right hand side of the screen

Comment: @Biscuit128 If you provide a live example, we could figure the problem out

Comment: the website is located at secondstory.co.uk

Comment: @Biscuit128 please make a live example on http://jsfiddle.net/ that reproduces the problem with the minimal code. I can't test anything on your website

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59799/discussion-between-biscuit128-and-singe31).

Answer (score 0):

try

```
@media screen and (max-width:1199px) {
    .logoimage {
        width:1%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
    .logoimage {
        width:70%;
    }
}
```